# VLOOKUP, For Each loop - write result to cell

Tags: vba, excel, loops, vlookup

I have the following table in Excel.

The `result` column is calculated by the formula:

`IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$B$8,1,0)),"new","old")`

```
ID1 | ID2 | Result
------------------
 1  |  1  | Old
 2  |  5  | New
 3  |  6  | New
```

**Problem:** convert the formula to VBA. I don't know how to write result to `Result` column.

**What I have:**

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim table1 As Range
    Dim table2 As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set table1 = ws.Range("A2:A8") ' ID1 column
    Set table2 = ws.Range("B2:B8") ' ID2 column

    For Each cell In table1
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell, table2, 1, False)

        If IsNumeric(result) Then
            result = "old"
        End If

        MsgBox result
    Next cell

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        result = "new"
    End If
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IsError on application.match or application.vlookup, not application.worksheetfunction.vlookup.

```
dim result as variant
For Each cell In table1
    result = "old"
    If IsError(Application.match(cell, table2, 0)) then
        result = "new"
    end if
    MsgBox result
    cell.offset(0, 2) = result
Next cell
```